# ffmpeg extract audio tracks only if it's not empty

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Is there a chance that ffmpeg will recognize that a audio track isn't empty and then only will export these non empty tracks?

for example:
I have a video file with 2 stereo tracks and only on the second left channel is audio, so I just need this mono track.

I'm currently using this, but here I'll get both channels:

```
-filter_complex "[0:1]pan=1c|c0=c0[left];[0:1]pan=1c|c0=c1[right]" -map "[left]" "%%~na_left.wav" -map "[right]" "%%~na_right.wav"
```

Comment: Not directly possible. What you can do is export to a lossless format like FLAC. Truly silent tracks will end up being very small. You can delete them in one go.

Comment: Maybe parse [astats](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#astats) output. However, it would work best scripted and you would end up with multiple commands (one to "scan", one to export). Or be lazy and just downmix everything into mono: the silent channels wouldn't matter.

Comment: thank you so far. Yes, I've already thought that I'll need to script first "scan" and than export. But my scripting skills a sadly to bad for that :(
It seems like I have to find someone who can script me that.

Comment: What's your OS and preferred scripting language?